# npm install a forked repo

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to update my react library from 16 to 17 for Material UI v5 migration, but was unable to update one of the dependencies.

When I try to update `materialui-daterange-picker` with a forked repo, I get a module not found error.

###### Command used

`npm install 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/jungsoft/materialui-daterange-picker/package?master'`

###### Error

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'materialui-daterange-picker'...
```

In my `package.json`, I have the following line

```json
{
"materialui-daterange-picker": "https://gitpkg.now.sh/jungsoft/materialui-daterange-picker/package?master"
}
```

###### Code

```js
import { DateRangePicker } from 'materialui-daterange-picker'
```